# Jersey Exception Mapper on exception cause

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, jersey, jax-rs

I am writing a Jersey app, and I use Hibernate as the backend. There is a specific error which I need to catch via an exception mapper, which is thrown by the underlying JDBC driver (`MySqlDataTruncation`). Unfortunately, Hibernate takes this exception and wraps it in a generic `HibernateException`.

I already have a generic `HibernateException` mapper which returns a 500 error. This is invoked to map all `HibernateException`s, including the ones which are caused by `MySqlDataTruncation` exceptions.

I want to register a new exception mapper which should handle the `HibernateException`s caused by `MySqlDataTruncation` errors and return a 400 error. Registering an `ExceptionMapper<MySqlDataTruncation>` doesn't seem to catch any of the exceptions that I want it to.

Checking the cause in the `ExceptionMapper<HibernateExceeption>` seems hacky. Is that the only solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, Jersey seems to have predicted this exact issue, and created a system to conditionally handle some exceptions but not others in an `ExceptionMapper`. While it is perfectly valid to check the cause in the general exception mapper, this seems to make the code cleaner.

One simply needs to make their `ExceptionMapper` implement `org.glassfish.jersey.spi.ExtendedExceptionMapper` rather than the usual `javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper` interface.

The `ExtendedExceptionMapper` interface looks like this:

```java
/**
 * Extension of a {@link ExceptionMapper exception mapper interface}. The exception mapping
 * providers can extend from this interface to add jersey specific functionality to these
 * providers.
 *
 * @author Miroslav Fuksa
 *
 * @param <T> A type of the exception processed by the exception mapper.
 */
public interface ExtendedExceptionMapper<T extends Throwable> extends ExceptionMapper<T> {
    /**
     * Determine whether this provider is able to process a supplied exception instance.
     * <p>
     * This method is called only on those exception mapping providers that are able to
     * process the type of the {@code exception} as defined by the JAX-RS
     * {@link ExceptionMapper} contract. By returning {@code false} this method can reject
     * any given exception instance and change the default JAX-RS exception mapper
     * selection behaviour.
     * </p>
     *
     * @param exception exception instance which should be processed.
     * @return {@code true} if the mapper is able to map the particular exception instance,
     *         {@code false} otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isMappable(T exception);
}
```

The implementation in this specific case might look something like:

```java
public class MySqlDataTruncationExceptionMapper implements ExtendedExceptionMapper<HibernateException> {

    @Override
    public boolean isMappable(HibernateException top) {
        return top.getCause() instanceof MySqlDataTruncation;
    }

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(HibernateException top) {
        MySqlDataTruncation e = (MySqlDataTruncation) top.getCause();
        // No possibility of a ClassCastException because we already checked
        // that `top.getCause() instanceof MySqlDataTruncation`

        // Do stuff with `e` to return a response:
        return Response.status(Status.REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

**NOTE: I haven't actually tested this (I ended up doing something else and can't change it now due to time constraints), and YMMV with using this solution.**

Comment: @mentallurg Thanks for catching that error! What I meant was that "Checking the cause **in the ExceptionMapper<HibernateException>** [which is the exception mapper which catches general HibernateExceptions] seems hacky," because it violates the single-use principle - the `ExceptionMapper<HibernateException>` should only deal with a single type of issue, not have to handle two different root issues. I never actually compiled and tested this code, hence the mistake, however I will correct it immediately. Thanks for the feedback though!

Comment: 1) *not have to handle two different root issues* - any exception has a **single** cause. It is not clear what two different root issues you mean. 2) *single-use principle* - really? May be you mean single responsibility principle. If yes, then again, extracting and analyzing the root cause has nothing to do with this principle. An exception mapper handles a particular exception, HibernateException. To handle this exception one may need many other components and services. But this has nothing to do with sticking to or violation of this principle. So your **answer** is very **confusing**.

Answer (score 2):

> Checking the cause in the ExceptionMapper seems
>   hacky.

Not at all. The cause is provided via a public method. This is part of exceptions concept, that exceptions can provide information about their cause.

Extract the cause. If needed, traverse even several levels deeper. If you don't want to handle `MySqlDataTruncation` in the main handler, create a separate class and delegate to it from the main handler.

Comment: If you find the answer helpful, would you mind to mark it helpful?

Comment: I stumbled upon a class by Jersey which solves this exact issue. Sorry for un-accepting your answer :)